# Inject specific additional products in product listing based on layered navigation active filters

Tags: attributes, categories, magento, magento-1.7

we are setting up a small online store on Magento 1.7.0.2, so far so good importing categories, attributes and products from XML and CSV files. Then I tried to implement what seemed to be an easy task to do but I can not get to my goal, here is my problem:

Suppose you have the category "Tripods" and one attribute "Weight_it_support", meaning how much weight a particular tripod can support without falling down. Then I have another category, "Cameras" and an attribute "Weight", no need to describe it.

Then what I want to accomplish is to have on layered navigation (or any other place) a filter with the attribute "Weight_it_support" and once I click it, show not only the tripods that supports this weight, but also the cameras with a weight less or equal than the one correspoding to the selected filter. Hope it is clear enough.

I thought that this could be accomplished by assigning the "Weight_it_support" to a set of attributes, select YES on the "Use in Layered Navigation" property of the attribute and nothing more. But these actions do not solve my goal as I need to also link the categories "Tripod" and "Camera" and this is not usefull as from this point I will have everything mixed up on those categories and we do not want that.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: No answer no nothing? I guess I will start a bounty as this issue is a must for our development and still don't know how to do it.

Comment: I may have a clue for you. I will spend let's say 1 hour on this in order to deliver a link to a github repo. If I am successful in this 1 hour, I will post an answer to your question. Otherwise, I will delete this comment.

Comment: Good to read this, thanks in advance, does not matter if your solution solves the problem or not, just by your comment you deserve some +reputation. We where just commenting this morning how SO can be such rewarding place to ask/answer and how much the communmity is involved.

Comment: Happy to help as much as I've been helped :) I thought about 2 solutions, the first one being the easiest and, IMO, the most not-confusing for visitors. 1) Add a block on top of the tripod product list with all cameras fitting the weight so there's no mix in the actual products list (people ask for tripods, why confuse them by adding cameras - let's separate both) - 2) Include cameras in the actual tripod product list which is the most confusing IMO and more difficult to code. I keep you posted anyway.

Comment: Hmmm...I understand your approach. Just keep in mind that the Tripod/Camera/Weight is just a sample, it can grow exponentially. I mean, we could have a whole bunch of different products with several different attributes that can link to other products. So the solution should propose an easy way of expanding from a "triplet" like the one on the sample to a way bigger number of combinations.

Comment: I understand. I will just finish my first proposal as I am almost done. I will then spend a very little time to see how to implement the second proposal for the Tripod/Camera/Weight triplet which may be a good starting point for you to implement for other triplets.

Comment: Bounty acknowledged as there is enough code to get started with. But I would appreciate if my last comment was answered...thanks @Hervé Guétin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version that creates an additional block on the "Tripods" category page when a filter regarding weight they support is active.

**Repo on Github**: https://github.com/herveguetin/Demo_RelatedCamera

**Wiki on Github**: https://github.com/herveguetin/Demo_RelatedCamera/wiki

---

**[EDIT]** GIT Repo has been updated with a version that works with full product list implementation. A block rewrite is mandatory though. It is the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List which is a commonly rewritten block.

**[EDIT 2]** Previous version was making 3 product collection loads instead of one when not mixing products from different categories (tripods + cameras). I made some updates that modify the original mySql query in order to inject statements enabling the addition of camera products. As a result, there is only one collection load even if we are requesting products from the camera category on top of the tripods.

USE WITH CAUTION : it doesn't work when flat catalog for products is enabled. You can turn this feature on or off by setting the constant Demo_RelatedCamera_Block_Collection::USE_MYSQL_UPDATES to true of false;

On a large product base (30 000+), you are very encouraged to use this feature and scratch your head to adapt it to your needs!

Comment: Man, here you have your upvote. Now will check if it is what we are looking for. Just remember in case this is the correct answer that unitl 48h I can not award the bounty. And evenmore, I'm about to go home and until monday will not check it out.

Comment: That's really ok. I'm trying to update the product list with cameras. This request may also be interesting for my own projects so I'd like to see how to make it work.

Comment: Great! I'm taking a quick look into the wiki and for now it seems to be what we are looking for. Maybe the 2nd option will be even more usefull.

Comment: I got a great track on the 2nd option. I am able to inject cameras into the tripods page but the pager is not working properly (new products aren't counted into the whole collection that enables correct paging). The toughest part is done anyway...

Comment: Ok...I'm at home so until monday can't test... one question, the rewrite of the block is done right into the core code? I've read everywhere that is lot better to override the class and leave the magento core alone and quiet?

Comment: You are definitely right : no change to the Core must be done. As of Magento best practices, the block is rewritten in the module. Please see the config.xml file. And, as a complement, it is even better to use observers. And if there really is no other way than using observers, one can use Core rewrite which will stand in the module that rewrites the Core - never in the Core itself. As a side note, I took the freedom to edit the question title to make it clearer if you don't mind (waiting for peer review).

Comment: Ok...perfect, any edit for the sake of better understanding is welcome

Comment: Ok. I think you at least have a good starting point and some reusable snippets in a module that respects Magento best practices.

Comment: Testing but I get this error `Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "1263" already exist`. Searched and [tried this](https://support.webcto.eu/index.php/Knowledgebase/Article/View/50/8/item-mage_catalog_model_product-with-the-same-id-already-exist) but then it throws `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.weight' in 'where clause'`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Bounty acknowledged as there is enough code to get started with. But I would appreciate if my last comment was answered...thanks @Hervé Guétin

Comment: If the line `const USE_MYSQL_UPDATES = true;` is changed to false it works and I do not get previous error. But instead of getting a list of cameras that match the selected on the `weight_support` attribute I get the full list of products for the current category.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty validation! I have remade a test here in local and everything works just fine both with const USE_MYSQL_UPDATES = true; and const USE_MYSQL_UPDATES = false; - I am creating a public domain with a fresh Magento install for you to check. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Yeap, it's working. Seems that there is something on my Magento configuration that triggers those errors. Tomorrow at work will try again. I'm accepting again the answer. One more question, can it be possible to do the inverse of what you have achieved? I mean, when clicking on the camera, show the tripods that can be used based on its weight. And with this we close the circle ;)

Comment: You mean: have a list of fitting tripods when on a camera product's details page? Will try to take a look by the end of then day (Europe time)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16579/discussion-between-yaroslav-and-herve-guetin)